# Calling AsyncTask from the Activity

Tags: android, asynchronous

For this code snippet( I have excluded the `doInBackground(), postExecute()` etc. )
How should I pass the Activity parameter while calling the Async Task from the CheckServer Activity?

```
public class CheckServer  extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    HttpTicket ticket= new HttpTicket(); //HOW IS THIS LINE DONE? WHAT PARAM SHOULD BE PASSED?



    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private class HttpTicket extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

         public HttpTicket(Activity activity) {

            this.activity = activity;


        }
```

Comment: Create the constructor HttpTicket (Activity).

 HttpTicket ticket= new HttpTicket(Activity.this);
 ticket.execute();

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity onCreate()

```
 HttpTicket ticket= new HttpTicket(Activity.this);
 //passing context to the asynctask constructor
 ticket.execute();
 //call execute to laod asynctask
```

Define asynctask as below

```
private class HttpTicket extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

     public HttpTicket(Activity activity) {

        this.activity = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        dialog.setTitle("Wait...");
    }
   protected void onPreExecute()
   {
      dialog.show();
   }
   protected String doInBackground(String params)
   {  
      //background opearation

     return "string";
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(String result)
   {
       dialog.dismiss();
       //update ui
   }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sipmly do

```
HttpTicket mHttpTicket = new HttpTicket(this); 
mHttpTicket.execute();
```

You could also delete the constructor, and just pass it to OnPreExecute as param. Then you give it in `execute(this);`